# Find custom post type url by author

Tags: custom-post-types, author, multi-author

In my blog (multi authors) I have posts and a custom post type named (listing_type).

In the site an author can have only 1 listing and many blog posts, and I need to find the listing url published by that author.

Example:

single-listing.php lists all blog posts (post) by the author

each blog post must contain a link to the listing (listing_type) published by the same author.

The main problem is that the listing url varies and I don't have a clue on how can I do this, any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query for post type `listing_type` and [author ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) within your loop:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listing_type',
    'author' => get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )
);
$listing_post = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $listing_post->have_posts() ){
    while( $listing_post->have_posts() ){
        $listing_post->the_post();
        the_permalink();
    }
}
// reset $post global to original value
wp_reset_postdata();
```